# facebook local currency initiated state testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing, payment

I'm implementing the new Facebook Local Currency API.
I got everything in place and I receive orders and callbacks from facebook, indicating the settlement of purchases.

The only thing left for me to test is the rare situations where we get a 'initiated' payment status from facebook.

The flow in my app should be :

- Inform the user that payment is still outstanding
- Wait for the facebook realtime update, indicating the settlement of the payment
- Send notification to the user that the payment is finally settled

My problem is that there is no way of testing this flow, since i can't force facebook test payments to go into a 'initiated' state, only 'success' and 'failed' states can be provoked in the payment ui dialog.

Anyone solved this problem yet, or are you like me just coding in the dark, and crossing fingers that the flow is working as described in the docs ??

/Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I think you can trust the flow to work as described. Already had a payment that was processed with a few hours' delay. And the real time update worked like a charm.

Comment: Great news. Now I just hope my code will handle everything correctly. It would still be extremely useful to be able to code a real integration-test.

Comment: Couldn't agree more :)